# how to abstract implementation in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have below query

```
SELECT SUBSTR(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''),2,length(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''))-2)
from
(select 'a' as colm from dual
union select 'b' as colm from dual
);
```

How can I hide implementation in oracle for repetative use. so by providing colm name as input, it just places this query from wherever its been called.

```
SUBSTR(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''),2,length(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''))-2)
```

Above computation is to be done at lot of places in processing logic, so instead of writing complex query again and again, I wanted to create a function or abstract this to use it at ease.

I know we can create a user-defined ODCI type but I wanted to know if this kind of implementation can be abstracted.

Comment: **Hint** : Create a view in order to save your current query

Comment: You may use [SQL Macro](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-0A638FCA-89C2-44E0-A5D5-0D09800D920D) feature available since 19c

Comment: no the inner query is not constant.. I want to use / "SUBSTR(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''),2,length(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),'"',''))-2)" /  for muntiple inner queries where "colm" field is generated in the inner query. hope i'm able to explain!

Comment: @astentx Tried sql_macro, it expects from clause
create or replace function my_func(inp_col clob)
return clob sql_macro
is
begin
return 'SUBSTR(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),''"'',''''),2,length(replace(JSON_ARRAYAGG(colm returning clob),''"'',''''))-2)';
end;

This throws error ORA-64629: table SQL macro can only appear in FROM clause of a SQL statement

Comment: @BhawanaSolanki `return clob sql_macro(scalar) as ...`

Comment: You'll need a `21c` version to be able to use a `scalar` macro, `19c` backported only the `table` sql macros @astentx

Comment: @MarmiteBomber yes, and I'm on 19c.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thank you, didn't notice that they ported table instead of scalar. This is explicitly specified in the [restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SQL_MACRO_clause.html#GUID-292C3A17-2A4B-4EFB-AD38-68DF6380E5F7) for 19c

Comment: 19c what? I think it was 19.7 where they introduced SQL macros. {select version_full from v$instance}